# libmproxy - how to load requests asynchronously?

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, mitmproxy, libmproxy

I'm wondering how can I load requests asynchronously with libmproxy or mitmproxy.

My code looks like this:

```
class StickyMaster(controller.Master):
    def __init__(self):
          ......

    def handle_request(self):
         ....

    def handle_response(self):
         ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using mitproxy's inline scripts, which have a `@concurrent` decorator: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/scripting/inlinescripts.html#running-scripts-in-parallel

Comment: Hi ,Is it possible to call an asynchronous method in @concurrent, because I want to send a socket message after the response is filtered.